# MVC. In some reason dynamic css style is empty

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to apply dynamically generated css style. The Action returns style content.
There are simplified examples of my code.

**Controller code:**

```
public class MainController:Controller{
    ...
    [ActionName("dynamicstyles.css")]
    public ContentResult GetStyle(){
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        return Content(".someclass{color: #0f0;}", "text/css");
    }
}
```

**_Layout code**

```
...
<head>
    ...
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href='@Url.Action("dynamicstyles.css","Main")' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

When I request the page there are empty style. If I make direct request to `httр://localhost/Main/dynamicstyles.css` - It renders right style file.
When I watching tab HTML in firebug, I can expand link and it shows right style content:
[image]

But CSS tab in firebug for `dynamicstyles.css` is empty.
[image]

And finally no styles applied.

What I'm doing wrong?

Additional info:
Controller has attribute like this

```
[BrowserCache(PreventBrowserCaching = true)]
public class MainController:Controller{...}

public class BrowserCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int Duration
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool PreventBrowserCaching
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public BrowserCacheAttribute()
    {
        Duration = 10;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(
      ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Duration < 0) return;

        HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext
          .Response.Cache;

        if (PreventBrowserCaching)
        {
            cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Duration = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        }

        TimeSpan cacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration);
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(cacheDuration));
        cache.SetMaxAge(cacheDuration);
        cache.AppendCacheExtension("must-revalidate,"
          + "proxy-revalidate");
    }
}
```

Well finally, how can it be possible, this:
[image: Loaded dynamicstyle.css with content]
and this
[image: Empty dynamicstyle.css w/o content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no words.

The problem was that name of css class begins with a DIGIT.
My code works fine, but looks like standards forbid names beginning with a digit:

[image]

The question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the '.css' in the ActionName and it'll work straight away.

Comment: No, it will not. Even w/out attribute ActionName it will not work.

Comment: Based on what information you've given it works fine, I built a test app to make sure of it before I gave my answer. Have you tried clearing the browsers cache or using a different one to make sure it's not a caching issue. Also what version of MVC are you using? Do you have any weird routes setup?

Comment: I use mvc 4. It really strange, I Had create a test project with that scheme and everithing work fine. Is there are any timeouts in html specification to load external css files? In my case real css generates from SQL data, but it generates less than second.